# Problem when deploying a NodeJS function using Serverless Framework

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, serverless-framework

I have an application with this architecture :

```
-Function1
  .index.js
-Function2
  .index.py
  .requirements.txt
-Function3
  .index.py
  .requirements.txt
-Function4
  .index.py
  .requirements.txt
-node_modules
.serverless.yml
.package.json
```

My problem is when i call **serverless deploy** i end up with the entier application in the NodeJS function (Function1)

[image]

This problem is happend only with the NodeJS function, the Python functions has only the code that's related to each one of them.

**NOTE** : I have this in my serverless.yml :

```
package:
  individually: true
plugins:
  - serverless-python-requirements
  - serverless-iam-roles-per-function
  - serverless-pseudo-parameters
  - serverless-plugin-include-dependencies
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I am using /typescript/es7 for serverless functions, please try this in serverless.yml:

```
plugins:
- ...
  - ...

provider:


name: aws
  runtime: **nodejs8.10**
  stage: ...
  profile: ...
  region: ...

functions:
  [function name]:
    handler: function1/index.js
    events:
      - http:
          method: get
          ...
```

Comment: Do you have also python functions in your application ?

Comment: No, but if you want to use both node.js and python in your project, I recommend you  will use docker. https://blog.morizyun.com/blog/javascript-serverless-framework-aws-lambda-python-docker/index.html

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use the Exclude / Include commands in the serverless.yml

So i just added :

```
package:
  exclude:
    - ./**
  include:
    - CreateThumbnail/index.handler
    - node_modules/**
```

And now the NodeJS function only includes the nodes modules dependencies and source code of the function.